# submit data from form into spreadsheet table

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to VBA and I am trying to get data from a vba form into my spreadsheet table.
I get the error: Run-time error 1004, application defined or object defined error.
The line of code it flags with an error is: `.Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = Me.FirstnameBox.Value`

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub SubmitNewUser_Click()

Dim RowCount As Long
Dim ctl As Control

    ' Check user input
    If Me.FirstnameBox.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please enter the users firstname.", vbExclamation, "Add New User"
        Me.FirstnameBox.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
    End If

    If Me.SurnameBox.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please enter the users surname.", vbExclamation, "Add New User"
        Me.SurnameBox.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
    End If

    If Me.AccessBox.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please enter the user number.", vbExclamation, "Add New User"
        Me.AccessBox.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
    End If

    If Not IsNumeric(Me.AccessBox.Value) Then
        MsgBox "The user number must only contain a number.", vbExclamation, "Add New User"
        Me.AccessBox.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
    End If

    If Me.SecBox.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please enter the users security number.", vbExclamation, "Add New User"
        Me.SecBox.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    'find  first empty row in database
    iRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1) _
    .End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.Range("D1", ws.Cells(iRow, 1)), Me.AccessBox.Value) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Duplicate Code Found", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

        ' Write data to worksheet
        RowCount = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
        With Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
            .Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = Me.FirstnameBox.Value
            .Offset(RowCount, 1).Value = Me.MiddlenameBox.Value
            .Offset(RowCount, 2).Value = Me.SurnameBox.Value
            .Offset(RowCount, 3).Value = Me.AccessBox.Value
            .Offset(RowCount, 4).Value = Me.SecBox.Value
        End With

        End Sub
```

Comment: what is RowCount value when it errors? Can you add in `msgbox RowCount` just before the error to check.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Hi Sam, 65536 is the value shown.

John - apologies.

Comment: I added an answer. You should try to avoid use of `UsedRange` and `CurrentRegion` they can give undesired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `RowCount = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count` to

```
RowCount = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows.Count,1).End(XlUp).Row
```

If RowCount is set to 65536 then trying to offset from cell A1 will be A65537 and will cause an error (assuming you are using Excel 2003), as 65536 is the maximum number of rows.

Comment: Sam, that worked well.. I changed the "Row + 1" to "Row + 0" so that all rows were used as the example you gave left a row between each entry. :-) thank you!